# Infinitesimal description of homogeneous supermanifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, homogeneous-spaces, lie-superalgebras, supermanifolds

Lie's third theorem says that if $\mathfrak{g}$ is a real, finite-dimensional Lie algebra, then there is a unique (up to isomorphism) simply-connected Lie group $G$ whose tangent Lie algebra is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{g}$.  Let me abuse notation and rephrase this theorem simply as saying that every real, finite-dimensional Lie algebra is the Lie algebra of a unique simply-connected Lie group.

In the context of homogeneous spaces, one might hope for a similar theorem: namely, that to every pair $(\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{h})$ where $\mathfrak{h}$ is a Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$, there exists a unique simply-connected homogeneous space $G/H$, where $G$ is a simply-connected Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and $H$ the connected subgroup generated by $\mathfrak{h}$.

It is not difficult to convince oneself that this is cannot be true: if the subgroup $H$ generated by $\mathfrak{h}$ is not closed, then $G/H$ is not smooth.  So we require the pair $(\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{h})$ to be *geometrically realisable*.  We also need to ensure that the action of $G$ is at least locally effective, so that there is no ideal of $\mathfrak{g}$ contained in $\mathfrak{h}$.  Such a pair $(\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{h})$ is said to be *effective*.

The theorem is then that every geometrically realisable, effective pair $(\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{h})$ is the Klein pair associated to a unique simply-connected homogeneous space $G/H$.

So far so good.

My question really is about homogeneous supermanifolds.  For the purposes of this question, let us take supermanifolds in the sense of Kostant: so a ringed space $(M,\mathcal{A})$ where $M$ is a finite-dimensional smooth manifold and $\mathcal{A}$ the sheaf of superfunctions.  I will also take Lie supergroups to be synonymous with super Harish-Chandra pairs $(G_0, \mathfrak{g})$, where now $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{g}_{\bar 0} \oplus \mathfrak{g}_{\bar 1}$ is a Lie superalgebra and $G_0$ is a Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}_{\bar 0}$.

I would expect a similar theorem to the one above: namely, that to every pair $(\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{h})$ where $\mathfrak{g}$ is a finite-dimensional real Lie superalgebra and $\mathfrak{h}$ a Lie sub-superalgebra (subject to some mild conditions, such as being geometrically realisable and effective) there corresponds a unique simply-connected homogeneous supermanifold $G/H$.

**Question**

Is this true?  And can someone point out a reference containing a similar result?

I would be happy already in the special case where $\mathfrak{h} \subset \mathfrak{g}_{\bar 0}$.